# What determines whether a character can use a weapon?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I found a new bow (Rank B) on the field, and while I've given it to my Archer (Rank C), he can't seem to use it during a fight.  What determines whether a unit can use an item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weapon has a ranking on it and the character has a weapon ranking. If the character weapon ranking is not greater to or equal to the weapon's then they cannot use it. The ranking goes from E (lowest) to A (highest).

[image]

In the bottom left hand corner you can see the characters weapon rank.

No luck finding a picture of a weapon description though.

Comment: Isn't S rank the highest?  Reserved only for advanced classes?

Comment: I didn't know about the weapon ranks - thanks!

Comment: @fbueckert No, in previous titles there were S rank weapons but in this game it only goes up to A.

Comment: Huh.  That's too bad; S-rank weapon skill used to confer some pretty decent bonuses.

Comment: @KatieK Yes, it's good to know, I reclassed all my units before a major battle and let's just say it's not so easy when most of your army can only use bronze weapons. =(

Comment: @Tony I just did the same thing and finally found a use for the Arms Scrolls I've had sitting around.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to @Tony's answer, it is good to note, that there are some weapons, that can't be used by just anybody, even if that character meets the weapon level requirement.

Those weapons are:

- [**Falchion**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Falchion) (Chrom only)
- [**Parallel Falchion**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Falchion) (Marth only)
- [**Wolf Berg**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Wolf_Berg) (Walhart only)
- [**Rapier**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Rapier) and [**Noble Rapier**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Noble_Rapier) (Lords, Great Lord and Lodestars only)
- [**Longbow**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Longbow), [**Towering Bow**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Towering_Bow) and [**Double Bow**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Double_Bow) (Archers and Snipers only)
- [**Amatsu**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Amatsu) (Myrmidons and Swordmasters only)
  (*List might not be complete and will be expanded*)

As well as any **Dark Tome**, which can only be used by **Dark Mages**, **Sorcerers** and any other tome user with the skill [**Shadowgift**](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowgift) equipped, that is: **Aversa** and if married to the Avatar, **Morgan** as well. Some enemies and DLC characters may possess the Shadowgift skill as well, such as Micaiah and Katarina.